# Subspace where an operator is positive

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics

Given a self-adjoint operator $\hat{T}$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and assuming it has a basis of eigenvectors $\{\phi_n\}$ such that $\hat{T}\phi_n=\lambda_n\phi_n$, one can consider the subspace
$$V=\textrm{span}\{\phi_n:\lambda_n>0\},$$
inside of which $\hat{T}$ is positive definite. My question is, does there exist a way of defining this subspace invariantly in terms of $\hat{T}$ without making reference to its eigenvectors?

(Some motivation: given the hydrogen-atom hamiltonian in quantum mechanics, $\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 -\frac{e^2}{r}$, the subspace where $\hat{H}<0$ is the linear span of all bound states, which correspond to elliptical orbits in the analogous classical problem.)

Comment: When you say $span$, do you mean the algebraic span or its closure?
The closure could be characterized as the orthogonal complement of the kernel of $T+|T|$, where $|T|=\sqrt{T^2}$.

Comment: You could also look at the spectral projection corresponding to the right half spectral plane.

Comment: Xogn: I mean the closure of the algebraic span. Do you have references for this characterization? Also, by $|T|$, do you mean $\sqrt{T^2}$ or $\sqrt{T^\ast T}$?

Comment: Sorry, stupid question; $T$ is self-adjoint.